# TypeScript object recursive type

Tags: typescript, recursion

I wanted to know if it was possible to use an object type in a function that composes it. In other words, I would like to use the current dynamic type in itself.

I think an example will be simpler :

```js
type Functions<Self extends Functions<Self>> = { [name: string]: (functions: Self) => void }

const run = <Self extends Functions<Self>>(functions: Self) => {}

run({ a: functions => { console.log(functions.a) } })
```

Here I try to access function `a` from its own declaration but it doesn't work because instead of a type I have `unknown`.

I know I'm pushing the limitations of TypeScript but I would really like to know if this kind of thing is possible.

Thank you so much for your help !